# My array won't read a two-word element as one single element even with quotes?

Tags: bash, unix

I have

```
validCandidates=(Tweety Homer Snoopy Popeye "Bugs Bunny")

for i in ${validCandidates[@]}
do
        echo $i
done
```

which gave

```
Tweety
Homer
Snoopy
Popeye
Bugs
Bunny
```

How do I make it so if I were to go through each item in the list "Bugs Bunny" outputs has a single element like so:

```
Tweety
Homer
Snoopy
Popeye
Bugs Bunny
```

Comment: try: `for i in "${validCandidates[@]}"`

Comment: Ah it was that easy... Thank you so much!

Comment: [How to use quotes in Bash](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)